# bash if statement inside the azure devops task is not executing

Tags: bash, shell, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I was trying to automate azure filesystem and directory creation inside an existing storage account if they are not existing already. I am using Azure devops pipeline task for this. Tried below inline script in both "bash" and "azurecli" tasks inside the Azuredevops pipeline. But its failing to check the existance of blob or files in the containers and simply passing the tasks without giving any error, but its not creating any resource either.
here all those parameters are properly defined as runtinme parameters within the yaml. Seems some issue with the bash script i am using

```
      - task: AzureCLI@2         
        displayName: 'create the filesystem ${{parameters.fsname}} & parent directory ${{parameters.parentdirectory}} if not exists'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: ${{parameters.subscription}}
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
                 existing_fs=$(az storage fs exists -n ${{parameters.fsname}} --account-name ${{parameters.storagename}} --auth-mode login)|cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/.//'
                 existing_directory=$(az storage fs directory exists -n ${{parameters.parentdirectory}} -f ${{parameters.fsname}} --account-name ${{parameters.storagename}} --auth-mode login)|cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/.//'
                 if [ "$existing_fs" = false ]; then
                   az storage fs create -n ${{parameters.fsname}} --account-name ${{parameters.storagename}} --auth-mode login
                 fi      
                 if [ "$existing_directory" = false ]; then
                     az storage fs directory create -n ${{parameters.parentdirectory}} -f ${{parameters.fsname}} --account-name ${{parameters.storagename}} --auth-mode login
                 fi
```

Comment: I'm not much well-versed with azurecli, but bash will never recognize this : `${{parameters.fsname}}` as a variable...

Comment: no.. but for my another task, its working as expected.

Comment: inlineScript: |
                  acl=user:${{ user }}:${{parameters.permission}}
                  az storage fs access update-recursive --acl=$acl -p ${{parameters.subdirectory}} -f  ${{parameters.fsname}} --account-name ${{parameters.storagename}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

if statement inside the azure devops task is not executing because the variables existing_fs and existing_directory are different from false.

You can use powershell script instead of bash script.

And the inline script can be as follows:

```
$existing_fs=(az storage fs exists -n ${{parameters.fsname}} --account-name ${{parameters.storagename}} --auth-mode login | ConvertFrom-Json).exists
$existing_directory=(az storage fs directory exists -n ${{parameters.parentdirectory}} -f ${{parameters.fsname}} --account-name ${{parameters.storagename}} --auth-mode login | ConvertFrom-Json).exists 
if (!$existing_fs)
   az storage fs create -n ${{parameters.fsname}} --account-name ${{parameters.storagename}} --auth-mode login
if (!$existing_directory)
   az storage fs directory create -n ${{parameters.parentdirectory}} -f ${{parameters.fsname}} --account-name ${{parameters.storagename}} --auth-mode login
```